# Create UTF-8 code from dynamic Unicode in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I am making a dynamic Unicode icon in PHP. I want the UTF-8 code of the Unicode icon.

So far I have done:

```
$value = "1F600";
$emoIcon = "\u{$value}";

$emoIcon = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{2,5})/i", "&#x$1;", $emoIcon);
echo $emoIcon; //output 
$hex=bin2hex($emoIcon);
echo $hex;  // output 26237831463630303b
$hexVal=chunk_split($hex,2,"\\x");
var_dump($hexVal);  // output  26\x23\x78\x31\x46\x36\x30\x30\x3b\x
$result= "\\x" . substr($hexVal,0,-2);
var_dump($result);    // output  \x26\x23\x78\x31\x46\x36\x30\x30\x3b
```

But when I put the value directly, it prints the correct data:

```
$emoIcon = "\u{1F600}";

$emoIcon = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{2,5})/i", "&#x$1;", $emoIcon);
echo $emoIcon; //output 
$hex=bin2hex($emoIcon);
echo $hex;  // output f09f9880
$hexVal=chunk_split($hex,2,"\\x");
var_dump($hexVal);  // output  f0\x9f\x98\x80\x
$result= "\\x" . substr($hexVal,0,-2);
var_dump($result);    // output  \xf0\x9f\x98\x80
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\u{1F600}` is a Unicode escape sequence used in [double-quoted strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), it must have a literal value - trying to use `"\u{$value}"`, as you've seen, doesn't work (for a couple reasons, but that doesn't matter so much.)

If you want to start with `"1F600"` and end up with  use [`hexdec`](http://php.net/hexdec) to turn it into an integer and feed that to [`IntlChar::chr`](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.chr.php) to encode that code point as UTF-8. E.g.:

```
$value = "1F600";
echo IntlChar::chr(hexdec($value));
```

Outputs: